# WEB SCRAPING - nightmare js and request

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am using combination of nightmare, cheerio and request in NODEjs, for making custom web scraping bot... I did authentication and filter setup with nightmare js, and now I need to call function like

```
    request(URL, function(err, response, body){
    if (err) console.error(err);

    var scraping = cheerio.load(body);
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

But problem is that I don't know how to forward loaded "body" (by nightmare). I can't use URL because it's dynamically generated content (tables), which means that URL is always the same... I tried to use this instead of URL, but it wont work. 
Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `request`. In fact, you shouldn't. Nightmare itself can pass the html data to cheerio.

Once you logged in and went to your desired webpage in nightmare, use `evaluate` to get the html. You can do something like this:

```
 nightmare
    .viewport(1280, 800)
    .goto(url)
    .wait('#emailselectorId')
    .type('#emailselectorId', 'theEmail\u000d')
    .type('#ap_password', 'thePassword\u000d')
    .click('#signInSubmit')

    //do something in the chain to go to your desired page.
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').outerHTML)
    .then(function (html) {
        cheerio.load(html);
        // do something 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```